# Using views & triggers for security instead of stored procedures

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers, view

Conventional wisdom says that a secure application should create stored procedures for insert, update, and delete operations. You would also use stored procedures so you don't have to use triggers, thereby avoiding some common pitfalls of triggers.

Another thought is to cover the whole database with views - so hardly anyone has access to tables themselves, they just do CRUD operations against views. That way, if you want to give someone access to certain columns, you can create a view for them that contains those columns, or just a computation. If you need to impose logic on update & delete operations (i.e. preventing someone from affecting more than 2% of the total rows in a table) you can do this via an `instead of` trigger.

In order to not fall into common pitfalls of triggers, (1) triggers should only update tables, never other views. (2) Triggers are never put on tables. (3) Views can't access other views. (4) If for some reason you can't do what you want by following the first three rules, create a stored procedure.

The benefit I see from implementing security this way is that you only have to create a view and maybe some triggers (average case - 2 additional objects) whereas if you go the stored procedure route you will always be creating at least 3 or 4 additional objects (depending if you create procedures for select). Also, our NHibernate mappings would be simpler because we wouldn't have to map three procedures for every object.

The question is if there are significant security holes or practical problems with using mostly views and triggers rather than stored procedures.

Comment: would like to see some references for that "Conventional wisdom", reading through sounds very complex and sure nightmare for any future changes to the application; this is not practical solution for handling application security

Comment: @K - What sounds complex? The "Conventional wisdom" or "triggers & views"?

Answer (score 1):

Ther is nothing inherently wrong with using triggers and views. As with other code they have to be correctly written and often suffer a poor reputation because so many poor developers have written bad code for them. For instance you don't want views to call other views because performance can suffer. You don't want triggers that assume only one row will be affected in the update/delete/insert.

Comment: thank you for your response. I added a 4th rule, views can't access other views. Although, I would normally file this under "good practice". The reason why I'm asking this question is because my coworkers have significant reservations about using so few stored procedures.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with using stored procs either, we use all three in our applications.  You simply need to design data access for performance, data integrity, and security. There are many routes to the final destination.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I tend to be in favor of using stored procedures for application access to a database.  I generally use a generic set of procedures which manage operations against each table and ensure data integrity.  All decisions regarding who can see or edit a given piece of information are handled in the application itself.   Only the app credentials have access to the database, any users that happen to find their way there are locked out, or have read only access at most.

I tend to dislike triggers that implement business logic because they are easy to miss when you are trying to debug something.  If all of my insert logic is wrapped in a SP I can pull up that SP and trace through it to diagnose why an insert is failing.  If there is also a trigger on the table which I have forgotten about or was unaware of, it may be a while before I realize it and remember to look there.  (though this is likely just a factor of my environment, if more triggers were used here I am sure they would be more prominent in my thought processes)

But I am not entirely sure we are looking at this from the same perspective.  If you are going to be creating different views each set of users then it sounds like they have direct access to the data store and are not working through an application interface?  If there was an application interface for this structure wouldn't it have to be updated and recompiled for each group of users in order to make use of the correct views?

I guess I am saying that stored procs work well for supporting an application interface or pre built reports, but the views and triggers may be a better option when users have read/write access to a common data store without an application interface in the middle.

I would also point out that there is the consideration of what is the standard for your shop.  If everyone else there uses stored procs exclusively, and you take another approach, then anyone else trying to come around later and maintain your solution is going to have a hard time.

In the end if it accomplishes the job without being a pain to maintain or causing other problems then it was a good solution.

Comment: @Rozwel, thanks for the response. This database is being accesses by a web application, although the data is sensitive so we have to take all reasonable precautions, which is why we'll be implementing security on the data level instead of the application level. However, I don't understand why you think the application would have to be recompiled for each user. Connection strings are a config setting.

Comment: @kelloti  I have never written a connection string that specified a table/view, just the database that contains said table/view.  The name of the table/view has always been specified as part of the sql command which would have to change for each client if I have understood your scenario correctly.  I suppose that the contents of the SQL commands could be stored in a way that allowed them to be edited without recompiling but it seems like you are basically back to a stored proc at that point, it is just not actually stored in the DB.

Comment: @kelloti Otherwise I suppose you could create a series of masking databases that just contained views pointing back to a common data store, in which case changing the connection string would accomplish what you need, but the handful of times I have had to work with this structure it was a major pain.

Comment: As a side note, I work for a government agency in the realm of medical records, data security it one of our primary considerations in everything we do. Our standard practice is that no one, except the core developers, has direct access to an application’s database, and even they are generally bared from making changes except in very special circumstances. All data manipulations are run through the application, and we use role based security to control who can see what. To the point that users in one location cannot even see most of the data on clients being served at other locations.

Comment: @Rozwell, you create a SQL login for each role or user in your application. Each SQL login gets its own connection string, so you have to do a little juggling in NHibernate session factory code, but it's not a big deal. Each SQL login has been granted or denied select/modify access on different views.

Comment: @kelloti  How does changing the user accessing the database change the sql command from 'select * from User_A_View' to 'select * from User_B_View'?  This is the part I am not following in your scenario.  Are you generating different SQL code in the app based on the current user?  If so how does having the code executed under separate credentials based on the user improve security?  Not saying it won't work, it is just not making sense to me...

Comment: The application is fully aware of which user is associated with the request it's processing. It also knows what SQL user & connection string to use, so why can't it also know what view to use? Applying permissions on database objects is a common practice - its one of the reasons why people might cover their database in stored procedures in the first place. If someone is able to gain access to the database (for reports, etc) they only have access to what they have permission. If your application already has database security baked in, that's less work to do

Comment: I still fail to see how this is any more secure or easier to implement than having one set of credentials that allows the app to access a set of SPs. It seems like you are just adding layers for subtle bugs to creep in. I would expect the structure you are describing to be a nightmare to update and maintain.  In both scenarios the app is ultimately responsible for deciding what a user is allowed to do. In a stored proc model there are 2+ layers to maintain and try to keep bug free. In the view/trigger model I am counting 4+ layers. (+ referring to how many layers your app is segmented into)

Comment: It has been a good discussion but so far everything is making me think that you would be better off using stored procs.

Comment: @Rozwel, I think you're struggling with some traditional security concepts. This comment thread is getting very long, so I suggest you read up on how grant/revoke permissions in TSQL works and how to use it in your applications to secure your data.

Comment: I am quite familiar with how to grant and revoke permissions in SQL Server, and I understand the technical aspects of what you are proposing. I just don't see the value in it.  The only possible advantage I see is if a set of credentials gets compromised they have access to a smaller portion of the data, but the flip side is there are more credentials floating around which can be compromised. From my perspective the two mostly cancel each other out.  IMO whatever slight advantage multiple credentials give you are not worth the other headaches this approach will bring.